# insertion sort code confused about order

Tags: java

Looking at the code below, doesnt the first iteration mean that i = 0 and j = 0 - 1? Why isnt there an error? I thought insertion sort was suppose to start from the end of the array/right side. How is this code accomplishing that?

```
class stevee {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A[] = {2,1,9,8,12};
    new stevee().sort(A);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}
public void sort(int[] data) {
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) { //access each element one by one
        int current = data[i];          //
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && data[j] > current) {
            data[j+1] = data[j];
            j--;
        }
        data[j+1] = current;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: because java use lazy evaluation so if the first part is false the rest isn't checked (In the case of && operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion sort works from the end in most examples. But why couldn't it work from the other side? 'Right' and 'Left' are only helping terms. Insertion sort is often explained with set of cards in your hand. Does it matter from which side you start putting them?

And there is no error cause `while` works also as `if`, `j < 0` -> condition not met -> block not executed. In while condition you have `&&` so both expressions must bu true, if first isn't, there is no sense to execute evaluation of second

Answer (score -1):

There's a condition for that case: `while (j >= 0`